# Javers "jv_commit" doesn't exist

Tags: javers

I'm trying to get Javer setup with my project.  I am using Hibernate JPA and I believe I have everything configured correctly.

Here is my Spring config:

```
    <bean id="auditDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.audit.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.audit.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.audit.password}"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="100"/>
    <property name="maxWait" value="1000"/>
    <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true"/>
    <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="true"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="${jdbc.validationQuery}"/>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="auditSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" destroy-method="destroy">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="auditDataSource"/>
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.audit.cfg.xml"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.query.substitutions">true 'Y', false 'N'</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">false</prop>
            <!--<prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>-->
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
            <!-- Hibernate Search index directory -->
            <prop key="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">${app.search.index.basedir}</prop>
        </props>
        <!-- Turn batching off for better error messages under PostgreSQL -->
        <!-- hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=0 -->
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Transaction manager for a single Hibernate SessionFactory (alternative to JTA) -->
<bean id="auditTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="auditSessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="javersRepoConnectionProvider" class="com.dsc.discus.ng.audit.javers.JaversRepoConnectionProvider">
    <constructor-arg name="dataSource" ref="auditDataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="auditController" class="com.dsc.discus.ng.audit.javers.JaversAuditController">
    <constructor-arg name="javersRepoConnectionProvider" ref="javersRepoConnectionProvider"/>
    <constructor-arg name="transactionManager" ref="auditTransactionManager"/>
</bean>
```

The JaversAuditController bean:

```
public class JaversAuditController extends AuditController {
private final JaversSqlRepository javersSqlRepository;
private final Javers javers;

public JaversAuditController(JaversRepoConnectionProvider javersRepoConnectionProvider, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
    javersSqlRepository = SqlRepositoryBuilder.sqlRepository()
            .withConnectionProvider(javersRepoConnectionProvider)
            .withDialect(DialectName.MYSQL)
            .build();

    javers = TransactionalJaversBuilder.javers()
            .withTxManager(transactionManager)
            .withObjectAccessHook(new HibernateUnproxyObjectAccessHook())
            .withMappingStyle(MappingStyle.BEAN)
            .registerJaversRepository(javersSqlRepository)
            .build();
}

@Override
public void addModified(BaseEntity entity) {
    addModified(entity, null);
}

@Override
public void addModified(BaseEntity entity, Map<String, String> extraParams) {
    if (javers != null && entity != null) {
        if (extraParams != null) {
            javers.commit(entity.getModifiedBy(), entity, extraParams);
        }
        else {
            javers.commit(entity.getModifiedBy(), entity);
        }
    }
}

public JaversSqlRepository getJaversSqlRepository() {
    return javersSqlRepository;
}

public Javers getJavers() {
    return javers;
}
```

I have to use BEAN mapping style because the JPA annotations are on the accessors of the entities.

Here is the JaversRepoConnectionProvider bean:

```
public class JaversRepoConnectionProvider implements ConnectionProvider {
private DataSource dataSource;

public JaversRepoConnectionProvider(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

@Override
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    return dataSource.getConnection();
}
```

}

I am doing a manual audit.  That is, every time an entity is saved, I'm calling the javers.commit() method.  As it happens, the very first thing I try to save causes a MySQL syntax error stating that the table "jv_commit" doesn't exist.  The documentation states that the necessary tables would automatically be created, so I must be missing something.  Please advise and thanks in advance.

Truncated stack trace:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'discus_eng_audit.jv_commit' doesn't exist
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4237)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2617)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2778)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2825)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2156)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2323)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
at org.polyjdbc.core.transaction.Transaction.executeQuery(Transaction.java:59)
at org.polyjdbc.core.query.TransactionalQueryRunner.queryCollection(TransactionalQueryRunner.java:86)
at org.polyjdbc.core.query.TransactionalQueryRunner.queryList(TransactionalQueryRunner.java:76)
at org.javers.repository.sql.PolyUtil.queryForBigDecimalList(PolyUtil.java:27)
at org.javers.repository.sql.PolyUtil.queryForOptionalBigDecimal(PolyUtil.java:36)
at org.javers.repository.sql.repositories.CommitMetadataRepository.selectMaxCommitId(CommitMetadataRepository.java:86)
at org.javers.repository.sql.repositories.CommitMetadataRepository.getCommitHeadId(CommitMetadataRepository.java:75)
at org.javers.repository.sql.JaversSqlRepository.getHeadId(JaversSqlRepository.java:76)
at org.javers.repository.api.JaversExtendedRepository.getHeadId(JaversExtendedRepository.java:137)
at org.javers.core.commit.CommitIdFactory.nextId(CommitIdFactory.java:26)
at org.javers.core.commit.CommitFactory.newCommitMetadata(CommitFactory.java:79)
at org.javers.core.commit.CommitFactory.create(CommitFactory.java:69)
at org.javers.core.JaversCore.commit(JaversCore.java:82)
at org.javers.core.JaversCore.commit(JaversCore.java:67)
at org.javers.spring.jpa.JaversTransactionalDecorator.commit(JaversTransactionalDecorator.java:58)
at com.dsc.discus.ng.audit.javers.JaversAuditController.addModified(JaversAuditController.java:56)
at com.dsc.discus.ng.audit.javers.JaversAuditController.addModified(JaversAuditController.java:46)
at com.dsc.discus.ng.model.persistence.dao.hibernate.BaseDaoHibernate.save(BaseDaoHibernate.java:146)
at com.dsc.discus.ng.model.persistence.dao.hibernate.BaseDaoHibernate.save(BaseDaoHibernate.java:26)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
```

Comment: JaVers creates its tables on startup, It's hard to guess why tables are not created in your case. It could be caused by database error. What do you have in your javers logs ?

Comment: This go me  pointed in the right direction.  Thanks.  The TransactionalJaversBuilder.build() method does not ensure the tables are created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Spring app, Javers instance should be registered as a Spring bean. JaVers uses `@PostConstruct` annotation and Spring calls `ensureSchema()` when txManager is ready.

See JaversTransactionalDecorator impl:

```
@PostConstruct
public void ensureSchema() {
    TransactionTemplate tmpl = new TransactionTemplate(txManager);
    tmpl.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
        @Override
        protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status)      {
            javersSqlRepository.ensureSchema();
        }
    });
}
```

In your case, this method isn't called because you have created the Javers instance in your Controller and not as a Spring bean. You should configure your app as docs says - https://javers.org/documentation/spring-integration/#jpa-entity-manager-integration

Comment: We have abandoned this endeavor, for now.  Regardless, this is the proper way to resolve my issue.

Answer (score -1):

It turns out that the TransactionalJaversBuilder.javers().build() method does not ensure the tables are created, like the standard JaversBuilder.javers().build() method does.  I am not sure if this is bug in the TransactionalJaversBuilder or not.  My workaround is to call the ensureSchema() after the Javers object is built:

```
public JaversAuditController(JaversRepoConnectionProvider javersRepoConnectionProvider, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
    javersSqlRepository = SqlRepositoryBuilder.sqlRepository()
            .withConnectionProvider(javersRepoConnectionProvider)
            .withDialect(DialectName.MYSQL)
            .build();


    javers = TransactionalJaversBuilder.javers()
            .withTxManager(transactionManager)
            .withObjectAccessHook(new HibernateUnproxyObjectAccessHook())
            .withMappingStyle(MappingStyle.BEAN)
            .registerJaversRepository(javersSqlRepository)
            .build();

    javersSqlRepository.ensureSchema();
}
```

Comment: You are drawing conclusions prematurely.